# How do I go backwards a letter?

Tags: ruby, string

Using `next`, I created a method that encrypts a password by advancing every letter of a string one letter forward:

```
def encryptor
  puts "Give me your password!"
  password = gets.chomp

  index = 0
  while index < password.length
    password[index] = password[index].next!
    index +=1
  end

  puts password
end

encryptor
```

I have to create a decrypt method that undoes that. In the end, this should be cleared:

```
encrypt("abc") should return "bcd"
encrypt("zed") should return "afe"
decrypt("bcd") should return "abc"
decrypt("afe") should return "zed"
```

I see that Ruby does not have a method to go backwards. I'm stuck with reversing letters. I tried to add an alphabet to index within the method, but I can't get it to do it.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: search 'Caesar Cipher'. Also, your current implementation of `encryptor` isn't quite right. Try passing `"zzz"` into your method and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that you can use `.next` to advance in a string.

Well, kind of, but there are special cases you have to be aware of:

```
'z'.next  #=> 'aa'
```

> I did this successfully

Not quite, your `encryptor` maps `"xyz"` to `"yzab"`.

> I see that Ruby does not have this option to just go backwards.

Take this example:

```
'9'.next  #=> '10'
'09'.next #=> '10'
```

As you can see, the mapping is not injective. Both, `'9'` and `'09'` are mapped to `'10'`. Because of this, there is no `String#pred` – what should `'10'.pred` return?

> Now I'm completely stuck with reversing it a letter.

You could use [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-tr): (both, for encryption and decryption)

```
'abc'.tr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy')
#=> 'zab'
```

`tr` also has a *c1-c2* notation for character ranges, so it can be shortened to:

```
'abc'.tr('a-z', 'za-y')
#=> 'zab'
```

Or via [`Range#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html#method-i-to_a), [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-join) and [`rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate):

```
from = ('a'..'z').to_a.join            #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
to   = ('a'..'z').to_a.rotate(-1).join #=> "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"

'abc'.tr(from, to)
#=> "zab"
```

---

Another option is to define two alphabets:

```
from = ('a'..'z').to_a
#=> ["a", "b", "c", ..., "x", "y", "z"]

to = from.rotate(-1)
#=> ["z", "a", "b", ..., "w", "x", "y"]
```

And create a hash via [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
hash = from.zip(to).to_h
#=> {"a"=>"z", "b"=>"a", "c"=>"b", ..., "x"=>"w", "y"=>"x", "z"=>"y"}
```

Which can be passed to [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
'abc'.gsub(/[a-z]/, hash)
#=> "zab"
```

You can also build the regular expression programmatically via [`Regexp::union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
Regexp.union(hash.keys)
#=> /a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z/
```

Comment: Or to `'a-z'.split('').rotate(-1).join` to make an intent clearer.

Comment: Don't forget `ord/chr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.next` to do this as long as you test for `z`:

```
> 'abc'.split("").map { |ch| ch=='z' ? 'a' : ch.next }.join
=> "bcd"
> 'zed'.split("").map { |ch| ch=='z' ? 'a' : ch.next }.join
=> "afe"
```

Then for decrypt you can do:

```
> "bcd".split("").map { |ch| ch=='a' ? 'z' : (ch.ord-1).chr }.join
=> "abc"
> "afe".split("").map { |ch| ch=='a' ? 'z' : (ch.ord-1).chr }.join
=> "zed"
```

Best

Comment: Note you can also use [`Integer#pred`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-pred) i.e. `ch.ord.pred.chr`. A shame there's no `String#pred` though :(